# Alert Volume slider sound file

Tags: 12.10, sound

In ubuntu 12.10, when you go to Sound -> Sound Effects tab and slide the Alert Volume slider, it makes a "pop" sound. What is the name of that sound file? I'd like to set it as my terminal beep sound.

Hint: it's not in `/usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/audio-volume-change.oga
```

Answer (score -1):

It is one of the files in `/usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts/`.

Comment: False. There are four files (bark.ogg, drip.ogg, glass.ogg, sonar.ogg) and none of them are it.